# Driver sound issues, complete Noob

Tags: drivers, sound, kubuntu

First I apologize if this has been asked before. I have recently (yesterday) changed from using Windows to Kubuntu. Unfortunately my sound is now completely gone. I've been trawling the web to try figure it out, but I have no clue as to what it is I am meant to be doing. I have no idea how to use the terminal, which is how a lot of the answers explain a fix.

I have a Dell XPS M1710 if that makes any difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Apologies again if this is a duplicate, but I pretty much need a noobs walk-through.

Comment: Forgot to add I'm running (K)ubuntu? 16.04.1 LTS. Cheers guys and gals.

Comment: Hi and wellcome. If you have no idea how to use the terminal, or a basic idea of how commads or scripts work, I recommend you to go back to windows, and install Ubuntu in a virtual machine to learn the basics before try it. Otherwise, you will have a lot of problems, trying to configure your system without the needed knowledge. However, using the terminal is easy, and after you have some experience, it becomes very fun. Did you tried the Kubuntu live system first? If so, there you got sound?

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. I was running it through Virtual Box on XP. 
I did have sound before installing it, no idea what happened though :( 
I liked it a lot so I thought I it was a good idea to install completely and XP is obsolete now and I have always wanted to try Linux..

How bad can i mess things up if I use the terminal incorrectly?

Comment: Well, you did something similar as me, when I started using linux. I was on Windows 7, and, one day I tried Kubuntu, and tried to install it on a second partition, but I did a mistake and erased all the Windows partition. So, I said like "F*ck this Windows, I want to use Kubuntu", and Installed Kubuntu as my Main system. However, the sound didn't work at the first boot. After reboot two times, it worked.

Comment: Haha I was the exact same! I will try the reboot and see if that works. 

Is there a way to find out my sound card is using the Terminal?

I am very stubborn and refuse to go back to Windows. I will figure this OS out! :)

Comment: That's the attitude!. To see your sound card, you can try looking here: [SoundTroubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting)

Comment: Thanks man, I'm gonna get this down one way or another Even if it kills me!! :)

Comment: Haha, yeah!!. Good luck! and enjoy your new Kubuntu installation. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks again! I was intimidated at first but I had a look at the terminal, I should be able to get it figured out! Thanks for everyones help so far. 

I really hope we can figure this out :-(

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your Dell has a HDA Intel internal, built in, sound card.

To check your card is a HDA Intel. Type this on command line (CLI)

cat /proc/asound/modules

OR

cat /proc/asound/cards

Assuming I'm right, getting the latest Alsa driver will most likely solve your sound issues.

Check the version of Ubuntu you are running on the CLI

cat /etc/*release

Also make sure you have dkms installed, you'll need it. You probably have it already, but just to make sure type the following on the CLI.

sudo apt-get install dkms

Go to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS, in your browser.

Download the right driver and just follow the instructions and you can't go wrong.